# A way to blit multiple buttons from a list with working alpha and color?

Tags: python, pygame

I wanted to blit several button choices depending on the number that a list gives, but putting them in a for loop makes the alpha() and fill() function stop working. Is there a way to fix this or there's a better alternative to code multiple buttons?

Starting code:

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT),0,32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
```

Button and Scene class:

```
class Button():
    def __init__(self, text, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 0, 0)
        self.updateText(text)
        self.clicked = False  

    def updateText(self, text):
        self.text = text   
        self.render = font.render(self.text, True, 'white')
        self.text_width = self.render.get_width()
        self.text_height = self.render.get_height()
        self.box = pygame.Surface((self.text_width, self.text_height)) 
        self.rect = self.render.get_rect(topleft = self.rect.topleft)

    def draw(self):
        action = False
        screen.blit(self.box, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        screen.blit(self.render, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))   

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.box.set_alpha(100) 
            self.box.fill((255, 255, 255))

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                action = False
                self.clicked = False
        else:
            self.box.set_alpha(0) 

        return action


class Scene():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def on_start(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.blitcount = 0
        self.optionList = []

        for button in range(5): 
            self.optionList.append(Button("button", WIDTH/3*2, 60 *(button + 1)))
            self.count += 1

        self.altButton = Button("Button without for loop", 100, 100)
        self.buttons = None

    def update(self, events):
        screen.fill('gray')

        for i in range(4):

            self.buttons = self.optionList[self.blitcount]
            self.buttons.updateText(str(i))        

            if self.buttons.draw():
                 print(i)

            self.blitcount += 1

        if self.altButton.draw():
            print("Alt")

        self.blitcount = 0

        return self
```

The rest of the code:

```
game = Scene()
game.on_start()

while True:
    clock.tick(30)

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit() 

    game.update(events)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know about this, thanks. I'll make sure to mark them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the order. You need to set the alpha channel of the box **before** drawing the box. Note that the box is drawn with the currently set alpha channel.
(See also the answer to your previous question [How do I change the text in a Button class for Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421751/how-do-i-change-the-text-in-a-button-class-for-pygame))

```py
class Button():
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        action = False
        
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.box.set_alpha(100) 
            self.box.fill((255, 255, 255))

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                action = False
                self.clicked = False
        else:
            self.box.set_alpha(0) 

        screen.blit(self.box, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        screen.blit(self.render, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))  

        return action
```

Comment: Wow.. It completely went over my head in the previous post that I should also change that part too, considering it works outside the for loop. Thanks